# Nulling an exception_ptr?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, exception

I have some classes objects of which I'd like to reuse after the occurrence of some exceptions. My question is regarding exceptions transported from other threads using `exception_ptr`. For example, several functions before starting operations (intended to be called by the object's user) do `if (_wrkrExc) rethrow_exception(_wrkrExc);`. I want to be able to reuse the object after the exception is thrown (which forces the user to deal with it). Is the `exception_ptr` nulled after a rethrow, or does that have to be done manually so the next check point doesn't throw again? If the latter, what would be a good design for handling it? Adding a `Clear()` or `Reset()` method doing a `_wrkrExc = nullptr;`, which the user must call before reusing the object seems to me class API bloat; alternately, doing something like the below seems ugly at best:

```
try
{
    if (_wrkrExc) rethrow_exception(_wrkrExc);
}
catch (...)
{
    _wrkrExc = nullptr;
    throw;
}
```

So any suggestions?

Comment: maybe `if (_wrkrExc) { auto exc = _wrkrExc; _wrkrExc = nullptr; rethrow_exception(exc); }` ?  This saves the extra catch-and-throw.

Comment: I tried this with a move() instead of copy, but the original exception didn't get nulled (though swap() works).

Comment: Exceptions should be thrown by value and caught by reference, not as pointers.

Comment: @EJP: `rethrow_exception` must be called with the argument type specified in the Standard, which is `std::exception_ptr`.  There is no other "should".